# If $A$ is positive semidefinite, then $A=USU^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

If A is a positive semidefinite matrix, then it has a singular value decomposition $A=USV^T$ with $U=V$. My textbook states this as fact, but I cannot seem to prove it. Additionally, $S$ must have the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ as diagonal elements, since $S$ is the matrix of singular values.

Edit: This would be trivial if all positive semidefinite $A$ are symmetric. In this case, $AA^T=A^2$ would have eigenvalues $\lambda^2$, where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, which are nonnegative by definition, so then $S=D$, the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Additionally, symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable, so we could write them as $A=UDU^T$, where $U$ have columns as the orthonormal eigenvectors. However, I do not believe this is true however, are positive semidefinite $A$ always symmetric?

Comment: This is a matter of definition. In mathematics, when $A$ is real, apart from the requirement that $x^TAx\ge0$ for all real vectors $x$, almost all textbooks also require that $A$ is symmetric in the definition of positive semidefiniteness. In other scientific disciplines, symmetry is sometimes not required. Your textbook most likely employs the mainstream definition and requires that $A$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right and the textbook is wrong. If $A$ is symmetric, then $A$ has a singular value decomposition $A=USV^T$ with $V=U$. However, when $A$ is not symmetric, this is not the case.

A very simple example to illustrate that the textbook is wrong:
\begin{align}
A=USU^T=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
s_1 & 0 \\ 0 & s_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\ b & d
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a^2s_1+b^2s_2 & acs_1+bds_2 \\ acs_1+bds_2 & c^2s_1+d^2s_2
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
As you can see, the matrix $A$ has to be symmetric.

Comment: Are you saying that it is not true that if A is positive semidefinite, A is always symmetric?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said (implicitly). Positive semidefinite means that for any $x$, we have $x^TAx \geq 0$. As an example, consider a skew matrix $A$, such that $A^T=-A$. It is easy to see that $x^TAx=0$ for all $x$, hence $A$ is a (somewhat special) positive semidefinite matrix.